# Segmenting characters from Image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am facing problem in segmenting following license plate images, while thresholding following images the characters are broken into more than 1 characters.. So I am getting wrong OCR result. I have applied morphological closing operation after thresholding the image, even after that I am not able to segment the characters properly..

[image: License Plate image 1]

[image: License Plate image 2]

[image: License Plate image 3]

[image: License Plate image 4]

The code used for segmenting above images is given below

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage *img1 = cvLoadImage(argv[1] , 0);
  IplImage *img2 = cvCloneImage(img1);

  cvNamedWindow("Orig"); 
  cvShowImage("Orig",img1);
  cvWaitKey(0);

  int wind = img1->height;
  if (wind % 2 == 0) wind += 1;

  cvAdaptiveThreshold(img1, img1, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                      CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, wind);

  IplImage* temp = cvCloneImage(img1);

  cvNamedWindow("Thre"); 
  cvShowImage("Thre",img1);
  cvWaitKey(0);

  IplConvKernel* kernal = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(3, 3, 1, 1,
                                                       CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL);

  cvMorphologyEx(img1, img1, temp, kernal, CV_MOP_CLOSE, 1);

  cvNamedWindow("close"); 
  cvShowImage("close",img1);

  cvWaitKey(0);
}
```

The output images given below..

[image: U Y and 2 are not segmented properly]

[image: U, P, Y and 2 are not segmented Properly]

[image: U 3 Y 2 and 5 are not segmented properly]

Can anybody provide a good method to segment characters from these images... ??

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10970473/2380071
Or this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14372743/2380071

Comment: dilation and erosion not working for me..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would like to show **a quick & dirty approach to isolate the letters/numbers** in the plates since the actual segmentation of the characters is not the problem. When these are the input images:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

This is what you get at the end of my algorithm:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

So what I discuss in this answer will give you some ideas and help you to get rid of the artifacts present at the end of your current segmentation process. Keep in mind that this approach should only work with these types of images, and if you need something more robust you'll need to adjust some things or come up with entirely new ways to do these stuffs.

- Given the drastic changes in brightness, it's best to execute [histogram equalization](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) to improve the contrast and make them more similar to each other so all the other techniques and parameters work with them:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

- Next, a [bilateral filter](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MANDUCHI1/Bilateral_Filtering.html) can be used to smooth the images while preserving the edges of the objects, which is something important for the binarization process. This filter costs a little bit more processing power [than others](http://eric-yuan.me/bilateral-filtering/).

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

- After that the images are ready to be binarized, an [adaptive threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) is used to do the trick:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

- The result of the binarization is similar to what you achieved, so I came up with a way of using `findContours()` to remove the smaller and larger segments:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

- The result seems a little bit better, but it destroyed important segments of the characters on the plate. However, that's not really a problem right now because we are not worried about recognizing the character: we just want to isolate the area where they are. So the next step is to continue to erase segments, more specifically those that are not aligned with the same Y axis of the digits. The contours that survived this cut process are:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

- This is much better, and at this point a new `std::vector<cv::Point>` is created to store all the pixel coordinates needed to draw all these segments. This is necessary to create a `cv::RotatedRect` which is what allows us to create a [bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20724615/176769) and also [crop the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769):

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

From this point forward you can use the cropped images to execute your own techniques and easily segment the characters of the plate.

**Here is the C++ code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>

/* The code has an outter loop where every iteration processes one of the four input images */

std::string files[] = { "plate1.jpg", "plate2.jpg", "plate3.jpg", "plate4.jpg" };
cv::Mat imgs[4];
for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
{
    /* Load input image */

    imgs[a] = cv::imread(files[a]);
    if (imgs[a].empty())
    {
        std::cout << "!!! Failed to open image: " << imgs[a] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Convert to grayscale */

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(imgs[a], gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    /* Histogram equalization improves the contrast between dark/bright areas */

    cv::Mat equalized;
    cv::equalizeHist(gray, equalized);
    cv::imwrite(std::string("eq_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), equalized);
    cv::imshow("Hist. Eq.", equalized);

    /* Bilateral filter helps to improve the segmentation process */

    cv::Mat blur;
    cv::bilateralFilter(equalized, blur, 9, 75, 75);
    cv::imwrite(std::string("filter_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), blur);
    cv::imshow("Filter", blur);

    /* Threshold to binarize the image */

    cv::Mat thres;
    cv::adaptiveThreshold(blur, thres, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2); //15, 2
    cv::imwrite(std::string("thres_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), thres);
    cv::imshow("Threshold", thres);

    /* Remove small segments and the extremelly large ones as well */

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(thres, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    double min_area = 50;
    double max_area = 2000;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > good_contours;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
        if (area > min_area && area < max_area)
            good_contours.push_back(contours[i]);
    }

    cv::Mat segments(gray.size(), CV_8U, cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::drawContours(segments, good_contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0), cv::FILLED, 4);
    cv::imwrite(std::string("segments_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), segments);
    cv::imshow("Segments", segments);

    /* Examine the segments that survived the previous lame filtering process
     * to figure out the top and bottom heights of the largest segments.
     * This info will be used to remove segments that are not aligned with
     * the letters/numbers of the plate.
     * This technique is super flawed for other types of input images.
     */

    // Figure out the average of the top/bottom heights of the largest segments
    int min_average_y = 0, max_average_y = 0, count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < good_contours.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point> c = good_contours[i];
        double area = cv::contourArea(c);
        if (area > 200)
        {
            int min_y = segments.rows, max_y = 0;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < c.size(); j++)
            {
                if (c[j].y < min_y)
                    min_y = c[j].y;

                if (c[j].y > max_y)
                    max_y = c[j].y;
            }
            min_average_y += min_y;
            max_average_y += max_y;
            count++;
        }
    }
    min_average_y /= count;
    max_average_y /= count;
    //std::cout << "Average min: " << min_average_y << " max: " << max_average_y << std::endl;

    // Create a new vector of contours with just the ones that fall within the min/max Y
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > final_contours;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < good_contours.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point> c = good_contours[i];
        int min_y = segments.rows, max_y = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < c.size(); j++)
        {
            if (c[j].y < min_y)
                min_y = c[j].y;

            if (c[j].y > max_y)
                max_y = c[j].y;
        }

        // 5 is to add a little tolerance from the average Y coordinate
        if (min_y >= (min_average_y-5) && (max_y <= max_average_y+5))
            final_contours.push_back(c);
    }

    cv::Mat final(gray.size(), CV_8U, cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::drawContours(final, final_contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0), cv::FILLED, 4);
    cv::imwrite(std::string("final_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), final);
    cv::imshow("Final", final);


    // Create a single vector with all the points that make the segments
    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < final_contours.size(); x++)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point> c = final_contours[x];
        for (size_t y = 0; y < c.size(); y++)
            points.push_back(c[y]);
    }

    // Compute a single bounding box for the points
    cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = box.center.x - (box.size.width / 2);
    roi.y = box.center.y - (box.size.height / 2);
    roi.width = box.size.width;
    roi.height = box.size.height;

    // Draw the box at on equalized image
    cv::Point2f vertices[4];
    box.points(vertices);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cv::line(imgs[a], vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1, CV_AA);
    cv::imwrite(std::string("box_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), imgs[a]);
    cv::imshow("Box", imgs[a]);

    // Crop the equalized image with the area defined by the ROI
    cv::Mat crop = equalized(roi);
    cv::imwrite(std::string("crop_" + std::to_string(a) + ".jpg"), crop);
    cv::imshow("crop", crop);

    /* The cropped image should contain only the plate's letters and numbers.
     * From here on you can use your own techniques to segment the characters properly.
     */

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

For a more complete and robust way of doing license plate recognition with OpenCV, take a look at [Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mastering-opencv-practical-computer-vision-projects), **chapter 5**. [Source code is available on Github!](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition)

Comment: How can we segment segments from final image ? (dilation and  morphological closing operation is not working perfectly, since in most of the license plates characters are very close to each other)

Comment: In the final image that you have provided the characters Y, 5, 2 are disconnected. So using cvFindContour() we wiil get them as different segments.. this results in wrong OCR output.

Comment: [You can](https://github.com/aperrau/detecttext) [follow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12785869/176769) [many different](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23104244/176769) [approaches](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/text/doc/text.html) [for this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23361583/176769), including the chapter mentioned above.

Comment: The technique I described is to isolate the area of the text. You are not supposed to use those intermediary results for text recognition. But you can use some of my ideas to achieve that, like bilateral filtering, adaptive threshold, etc.

Comment: I have tried SWT, and OTSU method before. But these methods are not able segment characters from the above image.

Comment: Alright, the newest OpenCV version brings new features for this type of task. You might be interested in these demos:  [end_to_end_recognition.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/end_to_end_recognition.cpp) and [webcam_demo.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/webcam_demo.cpp)

Comment: I'm playing with [`colorReduce()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20715062/176769) followed by `cv::threshold()` and having [some](https://i.imgur.com/lp67TX9.jpg) [interesting](https://i.imgur.com/B1I60Nz.jpg) [results](https://i.imgur.com/IO5Xgi5.jpg).